# Specific Port for RavenDB4 Data Subscription

Tags: ravendb4

I've included a Data Subscription in a C#/.NET Core 2.1 application targeting RavenDB 4.2.8. This was very solid as long as the RDB client in my code was permitted to randomly choose a port to use when establishing the client-to-database connection. Since the RDB client can no longer randomly choose a port, is there a way for the RDB client in my code to specify which port to use for monitoring the subscription?

Comment: You can set the **serverUrls** variable in the *settings.json* configuration file. It holds the URLs which the server should listen to. https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/server/configuration/core-configuration#serverurl

Comment: Thanks Danielle, we have set those according to the documentation you point out. However, the data subscription is a sub-framework in the RavenDB client assembly referenced by an application, and it chooses a port to communicate with the server at random. Your suggestion did lead me to try specifying a port that I know is open (443) in the application configuration file. But this failed to force the subscription to use port 443.